# Update values between dates and flags

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables below. Table A contained the Spike value 2 different dates on the same AccountNum 2018-08-17 & 2018-08-21 . I need to take the Table A first Spike_Reading_Day 2018-08-17 and find the match on Table B Spike_Reading_Day 2018-08-17 and find all the dates till before the last Flag 'P' Readdate 2018-08-09 and calculate the number of days. Once I know there are 8 days between 2018-08-09 to 2018-08-17 and I need to take the Table A Spikeval 150 divide 8 days and get the calculated value apply on the 8 days. Example 150/ 8 days = 18.75 and apply it between 2018-08-09 to 2018-08-17 on each date

Same apply to Table A second Spike_Reading_Day 2018-08-21 there are 3 days between 2018-08-19 to 2018-08-21 till the before the last Flag 'P'. So I need to take the SpikeVal 180 / 3 days = 60 and apply it on the 2018-08-19,2018-08-20,and 2018-08-21. I have tried different option nothing works because I have 2 dates on the same account_number.Any one can champion it? Thanks for your help

Table A

```
**FID      AccounT      Spike_Reading_Day SpikeVal Flag**
34166   TT0034166          2018-08-17      150        P
34166   TT0034166          2018-08-21      180        P
```

Table B

```
**FID   AccountNum  ReadDate    ReadVal Flag**
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-09  23.3620 P
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-10  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-11  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-12  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-13  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-14  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-15  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-16  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-17  24.1021 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-18  18.7660 P
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-19  24.5550 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-20  24.5550 A
34166   TT0034166   2018-08-21  24.5550 A
```

Comment: What is your backend, and when you say "apply" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Why is that FID is duplicate on Table A? Is there another Primary Key Field on that Table ?

Comment: Is Microsoft SQL 2012. FID is duplicate on Table A because they are the same account number is not an identity unique column. FID and account number are the same thing we use it for different purpose.